# Hide/show image on small screen

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-material, angular-material2

I am using Angular material-2 for my frontend,
I want to display different images for desktop and mobile screens

I have this code shown below

```
<div class="banner">
  <img [src]="images.desktopBanner"/>
  <img [src]="images.mobileBanner"/>
</div>
```

I want to display desktopBanner image in large devices and mobileBanner in small screens.

NOTE: marking display:none using media query is not the best solution as this might not display both the images together but if you check the network call it will still download both the images.

Comment: Use [`<picture>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/picture) or sourceset.

Comment: ok, let me try and does it covers most of the browser versions

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest you read these two articles:

- [Don’t use `<picture>` (most of the time)](https://cloudfour.com/thinks/dont-use-picture-most-of-the-time/)
- [Native Responsive Images](https://dev.opera.com/articles/native-responsive-images/)

The crux of these articles explain use cases for both [`<picture>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/img#Using_the_srcset_attribute) and [`<img srcset="...">`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/img#Using_the_srcset_attribute).

Essentially, if you are trying to show the same image at different quality levels, which is a responsiveness use case, you should use an `<img srcset="...">`:

```
<img 
   src="swing-400.jpg" 
   sizes="(max-width: 30em) 100vw, (max-width: 50em) 50vw, calc(33vw - 100px)" 
   srcset="swing-200.jpg 200w, swing-400.jpg 400w, swing-800.jpg 800w, swing-1600.jpg 1600w" 
   alt="Kettlebell Swing" />
```

If you want to show very different images, you are likely talking about art direction in which case, `<picture>` makes sense because:

> Why can’t we do art-direction with sizes/srcset?
>
> By design, the sizes/srcset syntax takes into account the viewport’s
>   width as well as the screen’s DPR. Adding art-direction into the same
>   syntax would have meant that the web developer has to explicitly
>   specify all the DPR and viewport width combinations in the markup.
>
> That would have made the web developer’s job much more difficult and
>   would have made the syntax much harder to grasp and significantly more
>   verbose.

So syntax would resemble:

```
<picture>
  <source media="(min-width: 45em)" srcset="large.jpg">
  <source media="(min-width: 32em)" srcset="med.jpg">
  <img src="small.jpg" alt="The president giving an award.">
</picture>
```

Both solutions have good support: everything but IE, as well as a way to fallback to regular, non-fancy rendering.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution using property `innerWidth` of the `window` DOM object :

```js
isMobile() {
  return window.innerWidth <= 640;
}
```

```html
<div class="banner">
    <img *ngIf="!isMobile()" [src]="images.desktopBanner"/>
    <img *ngIf="isMobile()" [src]="images.mobileBanner"/>
</div>
```

Here, `images.mobileBanner` will be displayed when browser's inner width is less of equal to **640px** (tweak to your requirements...), `images.desktopBanner` will be used otherwise.